# Migrate manifest v3

Tags: json

I can't install the extension because there's always an error in the service worker's registry, and the function, I haven't found the solution for days
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RencY.png)

I'm being the step by step of the migration and still I wasn't successful

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.